# How to check filename and variable name are same

Tags: c++11

Actually, the problem is, When system getting upgrade it should write "DISABLE_BACKUP" file in root directory. When it comes up, i have to check whether the file has been in root or not.

```
    if ((dir = opendir ("/"))!=NULL)
    {
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);

        //Here i have to compare the filename (DISABLE_BACKUP) with the string "DISABLE_BACKUP" and has to raise log entry.
        }
    closedir(dir);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)?

Answer (score 1):

1. The C function for comparing strings is [strcmp()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html):

   ```
   if (strcmp(ent->d_name, "DISABLE_BACKUP")==0) {
      // Found it!
   ```
2. Perhaps a better way to see if the file "DISABLE_BACKUP" exists is [access()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access):

   ```
   #include <unistd.h>
   ...
   if (access(fname, F_OK) != -1) {
      // file exists
   } else {
      // file doesn't exist
   }
   ```